# Authentication in Django. How can we make password verification step or compare the user ID with those in the database?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm trying to build a basic django web application. I am using the authentication and auth model now and my code requires username and password only. How can we make it better by adding password verification step or user id check service?

```
def authenticate(request):
    user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
    if user == None:
        return HttpResponse('username or password error')
    auth.login(request, user)
        #I requested "request"!!!!
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next', '/') or '/')

def signup(request):
    return render_to_response('signup_account.html', locals(), RequestContext(request))

def create(request):

        #user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'], first_name=request.POST['userfirstname'], last_name=request.POST['userlastname'],
    #                               email=request.POST['email'],
    #                               password=request.POST['password'])

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'],
                                    password=request.POST['password'])



        print 'create', user
    user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
    print 'authenticated', user
    auth.login(request, user)
        #Here what I want to do is to allow users to screen their wrong id.
        #+ Password check.

        subject = 'Thank you'
        message = 'Welcome home /n I am so happy'
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_list = [user.email,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER ]
        send_mail(subject, 'Wow, this email sending altorithm is working.\n What a marvelous function is.', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        to_list, fail_silently=False)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next', '/') or '/')
```

The below is the login html code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form" action="/accounts/create" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{csrf_token}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>User ID</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="userfirstname">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="userlastname">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign Up">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm a really beginner and I am even forced to think that this would be possible by inserting code into html file directly. I'm looking forward to hearing any feedback! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You have username and password there ... So pass that into try ...

```
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    if user.check_password(password):
        username = user.username
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, "Welcome")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(#your url
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Password not match")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(#your url
except User.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```